# Div's displaying on top of eachother when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed bar at the top of my page, everthing was working fine until I added the cards, everything is not appearing on top of the header when scrolling, but the cards do. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpvMe.jpg

This is the my css and html for the cards

```
@foreach (var item in Model.sessies) {

    <!-- Cards maken (probeersel) -->
    <div class="card" onclick="$('#div1').load('@Url.Action("Details", "Home", item)');  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#div1').offset().top}, 1000);">
        <!--<img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">-->
        <div class="container">
            <h4><b>@item.Titel</b></h4>
            <p>Verantwoordelijke: @item.Verantwoordelijke</p>
            <p>Datum: @item.Start.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</p>
            <p>Startuur: @item.StartUur.ToString("HH:mm")</p>
            <p>Einduur: @item.EindUur.ToString("HH:mm")</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
.card {
       box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       transition: 0.3s;
       display: inline;
       width: 370px;
       height: 250px;
       margin: 5px;
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
       float: left;
   }

       .card:hover {
           box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #406e8e;
       }

   .container {
       padding: 2px 16px;
   }

   .card:nth-child(2n-1) {
       background-color: #f2f2f2;
   }
```

And this is the code for the header

```
<header class="Header">
       <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
           <img src="~/images/logo_stijl2.jpg" alt="ITLab-Logo" width="150" height="75">
       </a>
   </header>
```

```
.Header {
   background-color: #406e8e;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem of `z-index`, to solve it give lower `z-index` to your header element.

```
.Header {
   background-color: #406e8e;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
   z-index: 1010;
}
```

Make root of your cards and give `z-index: 1011`.

```
<div class="cards_container">ALL CARDS ARE HERE</div>
```

```
.cards_container {
    z-index: 1011;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index:2; for your header's class & don't change anything for the cards.

Comment: What about the card's z-index ?? It should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 370px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #406e8e;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.card:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.Header {
  background-color: #406e8e;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 999;
}
```